# xpages custom control and dojo filtering select

Tags: select, dojo, xpages, filtering, custom-controls

I'm trying to make a custom control that uses a dojo filtering select. Set some properties for the custom control, such as server, database, and view that are available in the dojo filtering select for get options for control. So when I get the properties with the compositeData.propertyname command it is listed as wrong as described below. For a combobox is working perfectly.

Script interpreter error, line = 2, col = 45: [ReferenceError] 'compositeData' not found

The above line has the following command:

var server = compositeData.server

Does anyone know what can it be?

The code below

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect
id="djFilteringSelect1"
disableClientSideValidation="true">
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems3">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:
var servidor=compositeData.servidor
var base=compositeData.base
var baseNotes:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(servidor,base)  
var vi_origem:NotesView=baseSolucao.getView(compositeData.visao);
var nav:NotesViewNavigator=vi_origem.createViewNav();

var entry:NotesViewEntry=nav.getFirst();
var options = new java.util.ArrayList();
var tmpEntry:NotesViewEntry;
var option = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem();
option.setLabel("");
option.setValue("");
options.add(option);

while (null!=entry)
{
    tmpEntry=nav.getNext(entry);
    var option = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem();
    option.setLabel(entry.getColumnValues()[compositeData.coluna]);
    option.setValue(entry.getColumnValues()[compositeData.coluna]);
    options.add(option);
    entry.recycle();
    entry=tmpEntry;
}
return options
}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, can you add the full code of the filtering select, so we can have a look?

Comment: Hi Tom, i edited the description and entered the code.

Comment: Hi Marcus, just a guess; but are the properties for the custom control calculated? I see that the value of selectitems3 is calculated on pageLoad ($). If the properties are computed dynamically (#), it could be that the items are calculated before the properties are calculated. Try to set the value of selectItems3 to be computed dynamically and see if it works.

Comment: Great! It worked! I do not remember why, but I have to define it with a dojo filtering select in another application and I had to define the creation of the list of values ​​in the pageLoad. I do not remember the reason, but I know that defined as calculated dynamically gave problem, possibly performance.